# PHP script doesn't save text files on the server

Tags: php, html

This is the PHP script I wrote in a folder of my server:

```
<?php
$answer = $_POST['ans'];  
if ($answer == "yes.") {          
    $testo = "qwe\r\n";  
    $documento ="/other/yes.txt";
    $identificatore = fopen($documento, "a");
    fwrite($identificatore, $testo) ;
}
else {
    $testo = "qwe\r\n";  
    $documento ="/other/no.txt";
    $identificatore = fopen($documento, "a");
    fwrite($identificatore, $testo) ;
}     

fclose($identificatore);
header('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/other/poll.html');

?>
```

This code takes the answer from a radiogroup and if the answer is `Yes`, it makes a file called `yes.txt`. Else it makes a file called `no.txt`. This is the image.

[image]

This is the HTML code:

```
<form name="mainform" action="poll.php" method="POST">
<br />
<input type="radio" name="yes" value="yes">Yes, I like it.<br>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="yes" value="no" onclick="apri();">No, I want the old layout.
</fieldset>

//other code...

<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</td>
</table>
</form>
```

When I click the "Send" button, the script doesn't save anything on the server. Do you know why?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the directory that you're writing to? Does it even exist?

Comment: You may need to use a relative path as in `../other/no.txt` - using absolute paths may require something to the affect of `/var/user/public_html/other/no.txt`

Comment: Plus this is incorrect `header('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/other/poll.html');` you need `header('Location: http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/other/poll.html');`

Comment: Also, this `if ($answer == "yes.")` may not work in your favor if your value is `yes` and not `yes.` with the dot. Try using `if ($answer == "yes")` instead.

Comment: And this `$testo = "qwe\r\n";` may need to be reformatted as `$testo = "qwe" . "\n";` Linux and Windows react differently using `\r`

Comment: but It doesn't write the stuff on the server. I made a similar script and it saved the datas.

Comment: @AlbertoRossi I tested my answer below and it writes to it, without a problem on LINUX. Your code has many problems, and my answer is the only one that outlined them all, including your `header`.

Comment: @AlbertoRossi **Added note:** You may also want to use your answers as a counter instead of appending data which will eventually could grow very large. Have a look at my **EDIT** under my original answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First both your radio buttons should be called `name="ans"` and not `name="yes"`

Your `if ($answer == "yes.")` should not have a dot in it.

And your header is not properly formatted:

```
header('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/other/poll.html');
```

should read as:

```
header('Location: http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/other/poll.html');
```

- **More on `headers` on PHP.net: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php**

This:

```
<input type="radio" name="yes" value="no" onclick="apri();">
```

`onclick="apri();` does not belong in there. If you're going to use this, would be used in conjunction with a `submit` button.

This `$testo = "qwe\r\n";` may need to be reformatted as `$testo = "qwe" . "\n";` Linux and Windows react differently using `\r`

### HTML form (reformatted)

```
<form name="mainform" action="poll.php" method="POST">
<br />
<input type="radio" name="ans" value="yes">Yes, I like it.<br>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="ans" value="no">No, I want the old layout.
</fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</td>
</table>
</form>
```

### PHP handler

```
<?php
$answer = $_POST['ans'];  
if ($answer == "yes") {          
    $testo = "YES\n";  
    $documento ="yes.txt";
    $identificatore = fopen($documento, "a");
    fwrite($identificatore, $testo) ;
}
else {
    $testo = "NO\n";  
    $documento ="no.txt";
    $identificatore = fopen($documento, "a");
    fwrite($identificatore, $testo) ;
}     

fclose($identificatore);
header('Location: http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/other/poll.html');

// echo "ok done";

?>
```

---

> ### EDIT (optional as a counter method)

---

You may also want to use your answers as a counter instead of appending data which will eventually could grow very large.

**NOTE:** You must first create two files with the number `0` (zero) inside them.

`yes_count.txt` and `no_count.txt`

Here is a tested example of such a way:

```
<?php
$answer = $_POST['ans'];
if ($answer == "yes") {

$fr_yes = fopen("yes_count.txt", "r");
$text_yes = fread($fr_yes, filesize("yes_count.txt"));
$fw = fopen("yes_count.txt", "w");
$text_yes++;
fwrite($fw, $text_yes);

// will echo the counter but you can use header to redirect after
echo $text_yes; 
//  header('Location: http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/other/poll.html');

}
else {

$fr_no = fopen("no_count.txt", "r");
$text_no = fread($fr_no, filesize("no_count.txt"));
$fw = fopen("no_count.txt", "w");
$text_no++;
fwrite($fw, $text_no);

// will echo the counter but you can use header to redirect after
echo $text_no;
//  header('Location: http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/other/poll.html');

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

One problem is you are using $_POST['ans'] but your actual radio button is called 'yes'.

Also there's a stray closing fieldset tag in your form.

Comment: thank you it works now. I'd like ask you another thing: with javascript I write '<body onload="func();">'. Can I do an onload function (in body) with php too?

Comment: Ask a new question, along with describing what you mean a bit better

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. The php code can generate an onload function and return it on submit?  But if you want to call php on the page load without submitting look into Ajax /jquery. Like bokangles said, this needs its own question and more detail.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes, you should use a die statement when trying to fopen.

```
$fh = fopen($documento, 'a') or die('Could not append to file');
```

and if error reporting is on, you can always use **error_get_last()** to get a more detailed description of what's failing.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to write in / (root directory)
php user have permissions over the folder?

try this:
/project_folder
-poll.php
-other (create other folder with write permissions).

poll.php

```
<?php
          $base = __DIR__; //if your php version dont work __DIR__ try: dirname(__FILE__);
          if ($answer == "yes.") {          
        $testo = "qwe\r\n";  
        $documento =$base."/other/yes.txt";
        $identificatore = fopen($documento, "a");
        fwrite($identificatore, $testo) ;
        }
        else {
        $testo = "qwe\r\n";  
        $documento =$base."/other/no.txt";
        $identificatore = fopen($documento, "a");
        fwrite($identificatore, $testo) ;
    }     

   fclose($identificatore);
   header('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/other/poll.html');
```

Comment: `header('http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/other/poll.html');` is incorrect. [**Consult PHP.net**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) on the `header( )` function.